# Interested topics or Interesting topics?

Tags: word-choice

In a website profile, I would like to mention the topics I am interested in.

Which one should I use?

- Interested topics: Technology, Reading, etc. (Is it about the past?)
- Interesting topics: Technology, Reading, etc.

Even though this question looks simple, I think I have fundamental problem of understanding these kind of words.

Comment: Related: [What is the grammatical difference behind “is interesting” and “is interested”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16832/what-is-the-grammatical-difference-behind-is-interesting-and-is-interested)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Which one I should use?
>
> Interested topics: Technology, Reading, ...etc. does it talk about the past?
>
> Interesting topics: Technology, Reading, ...etc.

Grammatically, the correct answer is "interest**ing** topics". See the bottom of this answer though for a suggestion for improvement.

> Even though this question looks simple, I think I have fundamental problem of understanding these kind of words.

Many learners of English as a second language have problems getting the distinction between ing and ed adjectives right. But the basic rule is actually very simple. "Interested", "bored", "frightened", and all the other -ed adjectives describe an emotion. "Interesting", "boring", "frightening", and all the other -ing adjectives describe the **cause** of an emotion.

> This book is bor**ing** (cause of emotion) => this book causes me to feel bor**ed** (emotion)
>
> This person is frighten**ing** (cause of emotion) => this person causes me to feel frighten**ed** (emotion)

Thus, "these topics are interesting" => "interesting topics"

"I am interested in these topics" => "topics I am interested in"

> Interested topics: Technology, Reading, ...etc. does it talk about the past?

Here "interested" is an adjective formed from the past participle, so it does not describe the past.

However, if your question was about how to phrase this, a better way would be to ditch the word "topics" and just use "interests":

> Interests: technology, reading, goldfish keeping.