# Is there any difference between "I am having interest" and "I am interesting"?

Tags: grammar

If I say `I am having interest to play cricket` OR `I am interesting to play cricket` , Is there any difference in meaning of both?

Comment: Please visit [ell.se]

Comment: Please see the difference between *interested* and *interesting* http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16832/what-is-the-grammatical-difference-behind-is-interesting-and-is-interested Just remembered: You can also say *"I have a keen interest in [cricket]"*

Comment: I am having *grace* to play cricket. I am also having *interest* over to play cricket. *Grace* and *interest* are two interesting girls who like playing cricket. I am also interesting to Mr play cricket. Mr cricket finds me very interesting. Play is my good friend, but sometimes I call him Mr cricket, because that is his last name. Last name? How many names did he have before he had his last name? How many times did he change his name? When did he last change his name? Never mind.

Comment: I think you should be warned, Helping Hands, that neither "I am having interest to play cricket" nor "I am interesting to play cricket" conveys the sense you intend. The two most colloquially normal ways to express the idea, I think, are to say "I have an interest in playing cricket" or "I am interested in playing cricket." Since you seem not altogether comfortable with English, you should perhaps seek help from our sister site, English Language Learners; Kris provides a link to it in a comment above. I'm afraid that Blessed Geek's comment above is just a rather elaborate and teasing joke.

Comment: @SvenYargs - Yes I will use English Language Learners from now ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best *NOT* to use the progressive tense, be + *-ing*, with the expressions

- **to have an interest in** [cricket]
- **to be interested in** [cricket]

Verbs that express possession, (sometimes called [stative verbs](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/progressive.htm)),  e.g. *own*; *belong*; *possess*; and the verb *be* when it expresses states of mind or feelings e.g. *happy*; *tired*; *bored*; *interested* do not normally take the progressive tenses.

For example, *I have a wife and two children* is grammatically correct, but if we change this to the present progressive, we obtain: * *I'm having a wife and two children*, which is also grammatical, and correctly constructed but sounds as if someone is about to eat their family! (*I'm having a sandwich and two beers*)

Likewise we do not normally say, * *I am being interested in this book*, even if it does express a temporary situation.

*I have a thirst for knowledge* expresses a desire for self-improvement, the person *wants* to educate him or herself. We do not normally say * *I'm having a thirst for knowledge*, because verbs that express a need or preference such as: *need*; *want*; *like*; *hate*; and *love*, tend to (*not always*) express permanent situations. The progressive tense expresses situations that are usually temporary in nature, or actions that are in progress while we are speaking.

*“I have an interest in economics”* or the BrEng sounding; *“[I have a keen interest in economics](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+keen+interest+in)”* expresses a desire, and a preference. They  are sentiments of a somewhat permanent nature. The speaker is **interested in** economics today; s/he was interested in it yesterday, and presumably will be tomorrow as well.

Comment: Well thank you for the green tick, @HelpingHands it suddenly occurred to me what your real  problem might be, and  I just wanted to clarify/help.

Comment: Yep , Your answer has helped me and clear confusion which I was in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I have never met either construction. The first suggests to me that people have expressed to you an interest in playing cricket; perhaps they hope you will organise it. Usually it is expressed as something like "I am getting a lot of interest in ... " or "I am receiving ...". The second means almost nothing to me. If you said "I am interested to play cricket" I would know that you want to play cricket. If you say "I am interesting", you are claiming that others have an interest in you. But your example is a mix of the two that would mean very little to most native speakers in Britain.

Comment: I think my example confusing you , I just want to know difference between those 2 :)

Comment: @HelpingHands the answerer is saying that neither sentence is grammatical "I have never met either construction". You cannot have any difference in meaning between two ungrammatical sentences. You *might* be able to guess or interpret their meaning, but that's the best a native speaker can do.

Comment: I clarify. By saying I have never met the construction I am admitting my limited experience (despite my age). I am not expressing an opinion on the grammatical validity.

Comment: I am having interest is grammatically correct...we just don't use that currently

Answer (score 2):

In English, we say "I am interested in..."  Although grammatically correct, we don't say "I am having interest in". If you want the present progressive feeling, you can say "Currently, I am interested in." You can also use "right now" or "at the moment."

Answer (score 2):

I'm approaching this mechanically to start. Rather than trying to determine what the two sentences mean, I've isolated the words that differ, and assume you want know whether "having interest" and "interesting" impart the same or different meanings to a sentence like yours.

> > I am having interest to play cricket
> >
> > I am interesting to play cricket

The first problem I encounter is that the two sentences don't read like English, so I'll modify them as gently as possible and mark the most natural-seeming with asterisks.

"**I am having interest to play cricket**" could be:

> > I have an interest to play cricket
> >
> > I have an interest in playing cricket*

"**I am interesting to play cricket**" could be:

> > I am interested to play cricket
> >
> > I am interested in playing cricket*

Now we are comparing ordinary ways of talking about interest.

"**I have an interest**" is more distant or detached.

It might imply a long-standing interest. It can mean that there's something that connects you to cricket, and be followed by something like "My brother played for his college, you see." Having an interest can also mean being a part-owner. If you owned part of a business you could say "I have an interest in the local coffee shop."

"**I am interested**" uses "interest" to connote curiosity and eagerness.

You'd say "I am interested in playing cricket" to someone who plays cricket and might be willing to teach you how to play. There is also a business or legal sense of someone's being interested. If some thing is at stake for you in a deal of some kind, you're an interested party, even if you're not the least bit curious about it.

If this is about wanting to play cricket, I'd choose "I am interested in playing cricket."

Comment: Nice explanation of the different nuances in meaning.